# Parent state not updated correctly by children

Tags: reactjs

I am passing the increment function to a list of children (Row), but the count is never actually changed, I know that something about doing this in the children's useEffect is off. But I am still not able to understand this behavior.

Also, I am not setting the dependency array, because in this case, the count will run infinitely.

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const list = ["One", "Two", "Three"];

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleOnClick = useCallback(() => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  }, [count]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (list.length === count) {
      alert("yaaay!");
    }
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Count is: {count}</h1>
      {list.map((item) => (
        <Row key={item} name={item} addOne={handleOnClick} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const Row = ({ addOne, name }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    addOne();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return <p>{name}</p>;
};
```

The output is:

> Count is: 1
>
> One
>
> Two
>
> Three

Expected:

> Count is: 3
>
> One
>
> Two
>
> Three

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay i've created a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-x7xgnb?file=App.tsx)

Couple of things. first, you need to set the useState values through the callback function since we are updating the counter value continuously

Secondly, need to use `useRef` in the child component to make sure child component is visited In each iteration. Do the checking inside child component `useEffect`

```
export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
    
  const handleOnClick = React.useCallback(() => {
    setCount((count) => count + 1);
  }, [count, setCount]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (list.length === count) {
      alert('yaaay!');
    }
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Count is: {count}</h1>
      {list.map((item) => (
        <Row key={item} name={item} addOne={handleOnClick} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const Row =({ addOne, name }) => {
  const dataFetchedRef = React.useRef(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (dataFetchedRef.current) return;
    dataFetchedRef.current = true;
    addOne();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [name]);

  return <p>{name}</p>;
};
```

Comment: _"Secondly, need to use useRef in the child component to make sure child component is visited In each iteration."_ - but... why?

Comment: check the side-effect section https://upmostly.com/tutorials/why-is-my-useeffect-hook-running-twice-in-react

Comment: Now I get it, that React batches all the changes before rendering the component, thanks!

Comment: So you suggest him to add extra, redundant code just to make this one work properly in development mode? Are you aware that this issue wont occur in production mode? Anyways, if you are so enthusiastic about react theory, patterns and rules, you should definitely tell the OP that the approach he chose does not make any sense.

Comment: I am indeed sceptical about the second point though (will dig more into it), but if it's just because of the double render in dev mode, then it should be okay to keep the code as is.

Comment: In my app, I am able to enable/disable this functionality in dev mode easily by toggling React.StrictMode when needed.